# Area under the Curve meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, auc

I am looking for an **R** function to perform a meta-analysis on areas under the curve (AUCs) of a diagnostic model.
There is a model, which is validated in 5 other papers and each report an AUC with 95-percent confidence interval. How can I pool these AUCs into a single estimate by using meta-analysis?

Comment: Have you thought of looking at the CRAN task view on MetaAnalysis? You should find at least one package dedicated to prognostic studies there.

Comment: @mdewey I couldn't find any on: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MetaAnalysis.html Am i overlooking it?

Comment: Try searching that file for the word prognostic

Comment: You mean a clinical prediction model, right? Such as the Framingham Risk Score?